# Spotfire: calculating difference between two rows in same column based on attributes in different columns

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and need help in getting the right expression for a calculated column.

My Data contains different subjects grouped in column `ID`. For every ID, Bodyweight was measured on different days. Days are given in column `Day` and stated as 1,2,3...

The last day is denoted by `Last` and Bodyweight measurements given in another column. Another column is present which is called `Baseline`. The Body weight measured is considered as baseline if the column contains a `Y` for that row.

I need to insert a calculated column, which will contain the difference between `Body measurement` measured on `Day` denoted `Last` and  `Body measurement`  marked by `Y` in column `Baseline`.

This should be done for every new ID. I am not able to figure this out. Could someone advise me on how to go about it?

[Here is an example attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jiBo.jpg)

[image]

So, the calculated column for Rita will give **-4** (body weight at `Last=56` and BodyWeight at `baseline=56`, so 52-56 =**-4**)

Answer (score 1):

the sample data you provided is a little weird, particularly the `[Day]` column. if it's within your control, I suggest to use actual dates rather than a number/string here.

barring that, I was able to get your desired results, but it required two calculated columns: the first one will consolidate the `[Day]` and `[Baseline]` columns into a single column, and the second one contains your desired info.

column 1, which I called `Day (int)`:

```
CASE  
  WHEN [Day]="Last" THEN 1000000 
  WHEN [Baseline]="Y" THEN -1000000 
  WHEN [Day]!="Last" THEN Integer([Day])
END
```

I picked a random high and low max to establish a chronological order. this will put `1000000` in place of "Last" (if you have any programs that are longer than one million days, you'll need to increase this number). the same for the `[Baseline]` column, but that value will be `-1000000`, which is presumably the lowest value you will ever see in this column. **both of these are assumptions and may not work for your implementation**. finally, in all other cases, the day number will be used.

column 2, which I called `Diff`:

```
Last([Weight]) OVER (Intersect([Name],LastNode([Day (int)]))) -
First([Weight]) OVER (Intersect([Name],FirstNode([Day (int)])))
```

the first line uses what's called an [`OVER` expression](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.2/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_over_in_custom_expressions.htm) to retrieve the first value for `[Weight]`, ordered by `[Day (int)]`, per `[Name]`. the second line gives the reverse of that, and so the difference is calculated as `-4` (or whatever is appropriate).